# Inter dependent filter api in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I want to expose the sample dataset through a single generic HTTP API endpoint, which is capable of filtering, grouping and sorting.
In this I want API to be interdependent. For eg. If I have to show the number of impressions and clicks that occurred before the 1st of June 2017, broken down by channel and country, sorted by clicks in descending order.
I know how to perform singular operation in django filter by using django ORM and django rest_framework_filters but I'm completely unaware of this problem statement. Any sort of help will be appreciated.

This is my view:
    class filter_dataset(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AdjustDatasetSerializers
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ('revenue', 'spend', 'OS', 'date')
    filterset_class = ProductFilter

```
def get_queryset(self):
    dataset = Dataset.objects.all()
    return dataset

def get(self, request):
    dataset = self.get_queryset()
    serializer = self.serializer_class(dataset, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This is my serializer class:

```
class AdjustDatasetSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Dataset
    fields = (
        'date',
        'channel',
        'OS',
        'impressions',
        'clicks',
        'installs',
        'spend',
        'revenue',
    )
```

And this is my models.py:

```
class Dataset(models.Model):
date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=255,auto_now_add=True)
channel = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
OS = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
impressions = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
clicks = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
installs = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
spend = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
revenue = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Hi Chirag - can we have some more detail please, include your models.py, serializers.py and viewsets.py.

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts I have updated the question, Please check.

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts I have made the filter but that doesn't seems working, no matter what changes I make and what  do it always return me the same queryset.